# How to post a request to .aspx page with python

Tags: python, asp.net, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to scrape the following website: https://wwwapps.ncmedboard.org/Clients/NCBOM/Public/LicenseeInformationResults.aspx

In order to get each page to scrape, I need to first conduct a search on this .aspx page by inputting a first name and last name and initiating the search.

Using resources on the internet, I put together the following http POST request:

```
url = 'https://wwwapps.ncmedboard.org/Clients/NCBOM/Public/LicenseeInformationResults.aspx'

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,zh;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.5'
}

session = requests.session()
response = session.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
form_data = {
    '__VIEWSTATE': soup.find('input', {'name': '__VIEWSTATE'}).get('value'),
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': soup.find('input', {'name': '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'}).get('value'),
    'waLastName':'Smith',
    'waFirstName':'John',
    '__EVENTTARGET':'btnNext'
}

f = session.post(url, data=form_data, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.content, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print("Found the URL:" + a['href'])
```

It doesn't seem like the post has any effect, since when you look at the html after the post request, it doesn't seem to show the results page. Any pointers on why this is the case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you may have to set asp.net session cookie which will be generated new for each new session. which in your website's case (https://wwwapps.ncmedboard.org) is ASP.NET_SessionId=(value of your sessionid provided by website)

if CSRF is not validated correctly it will may be bypass it.